# Tricks to speed up the combat of 3.5 D&D?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

While I would like to ask this question of many other games the answer to each system of rules would undoubtedly be vary different and it'd be too heavy-handed a question to address.

**So In regards to D&D 3.5 alone**, as you gain levels and the BAB raises with your characters thus the number of attacks they are capable of in a turn, **and** the monsters you face similarly begin gaining more attacks or perhaps in unfortunate situations more tentacles, heads and other nasty bits, *are there any simple tricks for keeping combat moving, driving and exciting?*

I do enjoy the rp sections of the game and tend to allow the narrative to absorb most of our campaigns (which my group is quite fond of as well), but of course every now and again you need a really good epic battle with a dragon, and it's a shame if the fight with said dragon ends up disappointing because one round took up our entire play session.

Such examples might include: *better ways to track the calculations the fighters need to make every time they attack? Quick tricks to save time like rolling attack and damage at the same time.* That sort of thing.

I'm sure there are many of you out there who love D&D and have struggled with this and found your own brilliant solutions to such problems without having to put D&D on a bookshelf and play something else.